# Can I listen to ports other than 80 on Joyent's no.de development environment?

Tags: node.js, port, joyent

I recently provisioned a Node SmartMachine on Joyent's free development platform. I'm having trouble getting my Node server to listen to any port other than 80.

This works:

```
server.listen( 80 );
```

When I visit http://[my machine].no.de/, I see my expected output.

However, if I try:

```
server.listen( 3000 );
```

and visit the page on the corresponding port, I'll get something like "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to [my machine].no.de:3000"

I haven't found anything useful on http://wiki.joyent.com/. Does anyone have any insights into what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ssh in there (like you would do in a normal VPS), you can start apps on different ports also, but not through their git-deployment system (which will auto start your app only on port 80). I actually did that and know for a fact it works.

Look at this: http://alessio.no.de:3000/

Comment: I have tried to set this up on another port, however, without much success. Can you give me some more details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well chances are that Joyent did not allow connections from port other than 80.